# Python Requests Not Cleaning up Connections and Causing Port Overflow?

Tags: python, rest, networking, ssh, python-requests

I'm doing something fairly outside of my comfort zone here, so hopefully I'm just doing something stupid.

I have an Amazon EC2 instance which I'm using to run a specialized database, which is controlled through a webapp inside of Tomcat that provides a REST API. On the same server, I'm running a Python script that uses the Requests library to make hundreds of thousands of simple queries to the database (I don't think it's possible to consolidate the queries, though I am going to try that next.)

The problem: after running the script for a bit, I suddenly get a **broken pipe** error on my SSH terminal. When I try to log back in with SSH, I keep getting "operation timed out" errors. So I can't even log back in to terminate the Python process and instead have to reboot the EC2 instance (which is a huge pain, especially since I'm using ephemeral storage)

My theory is that each time requests makes a REST call, it activates a pair of ports between  Python and Tomcat, but that it never closes the ports when it's done. So python keeps trying to grab more and more ports and eventually either somehow grabs away and locks the SSH port (booting me off), or it just uses all the ports and that causes the network system to crap out somehow (as I said, I'm out of my depth.)

I also tried using `httplib2`, and was getting a similar problem.

Any ideas? If my port theory is correct, is there a way to force requests to surrender the port when it's done? Or otherwise is there at least a way to tell Ubuntu to keep the SSH port off-limits so that I can at least log back in and terminate the process?

Or is there some sort of best practice to using Python to make lots and lots of very simple REST calls?

Edit:

Solved...do:

```
s = requests.session()
s.config['keep_alive'] = False
```

Before making the request to force Requests to release connections when it's done.

Comment: Could we see the bit of code that you are using to make the requests? Are you using the async module or doing them in some kind of loop? What does the log for the tomcat server say?

Comment: Am now getting `AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'config'`. I assume the library has changed. Is there a new way to disable keep alive?

Answer (score 2):

My speculation:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/requests/models.py#L539 sets conn to connectionpool.connection_from_url(url)

That leads to https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L562, which leads to https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L167.

This eventually leads to https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L185:

```
def _new_conn(self):
    """
    Return a fresh :class:`httplib.HTTPConnection`.
    """
    self.num_connections += 1
    log.info("Starting new HTTP connection (%d): %s" %
             (self.num_connections, self.host))
    return HTTPConnection(host=self.host, port=self.port)
```

I would suggest hooking a handler up to that logger, and listening for lines that match that one. That would let you see how many connections are being created.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...Requests has a default 'Keep Alive' policy on connections which you have to explicitly override by doing

```
s = requests.session()
s.config['keep_alive'] = False
```

before you make a request.

From the doc:

"""
Keep-Alive
Excellent news — thanks to urllib3, keep-alive is 100% automatic within a session! Any requests that you make within a session will automatically reuse the appropriate connection!

Note that connections are only released back to the pool for reuse once all body data has been read; be sure to either set prefetch to True or read the content property of the Response object.

If you’d like to disable keep-alive, you can simply set the keep_alive configuration to False:

s = requests.session()
s.config['keep_alive'] = False
"""

There may be a subtle bug in Requests here because I WAS reading the .text and .content properties and it was still not releasing the connections. But explicitly passing 'keep alive' as false fixed the problem.

Comment: Please provide a complete example.